# How to fetch all data from table without having an entity which maps one-to-one with table columns using spring boot jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a spring boot application where I am using JpaRepository. I am trying to create a service which will return entire data set from a table.

My table has 170 fields and it keeps growing. In my Entity class I don't want to write code for 170 columns to map each and every field.

Is there any way I can get everything from table in map?? And then iterate over it to fetch column name vs column value.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The JPARepository will not allow this, since it is typed by the Generics. If you know a way to get the used Entitymanager, you can revert to the original way of getting data from a sql-database.

```java
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select * from <tablename>");
  List<Object[]> results = q.getResultList();
```

*results* will contain records of Arrays. These arrays will represent the records of your table.

Comment: Can I directly use tables name in the select query?? I believe we can only use Entity name in that select query. Can you please confirm?

Comment: if you use createNativeQuery. It is like using JDBC directly. Look it up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could get the data. But it doesn't return column names. I need to map column name vs column data. Any insights??

Comment: that depends on the dbms you are using. The Meta-Data mostly in the information_schema. See [information_schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema)